# 'FETCH' command with a 'BAD' response: Error in IMAP command FETCH: Invalid messageset (0.001 + 0.000 secs). on DoveCot IMAP Server

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, imap

I'm hosting my webserver using postfix and dovecot. it works fine when i try to connect using my iphone and my macbook.
I need to connect an external WebbApplication to get all E-Mails over IMAP Connection. The connection can be authenticated. I just can't get all mails. I get the following response:

```
The IMAP server replied to the 'FETCH' command with a 'BAD' response: Error in IMAP command FETCH: Invalid messageset (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
```

The WebApplication is working with other webservers like google and gmx.
So it should be a problem with my webserver.
I'm really lost and i can't know where to look in.

The Version of dovecot is:

```
2.2.33.2 (d6601f4ec)
```

Thanks for any help in advanced!

############## Edit ##############

following is the syslog file at the moment when i request the fetch:

```
    Nov 10 21:10:06 mail postfix/local[8772]: 5D71E24369A: to=<opendkim@mail.domain.com>, orig_to=<opendkim>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Nov 10 21:10:06 mail postfix/qmgr[23043]: 5D71E24369A: removed
Nov 10 21:10:06 mail xrdp[1122]: (1122)(140578514478912)[INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:198.27.104.24 port 53740
Nov 10 21:10:06 mail xrdp[1122]: (1122)(140578514478912)[DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.20.11.1 port 3389)
Nov 10 21:10:06 mail xrdp[19460]: (19460)(140578514478912)[DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
Nov 10 21:10:06 mail xrdp[19460]: (19460)(140578514478912)[INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
Nov 10 21:10:06 mail xrdp[19460]: (19460)(140578514478912)[INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
Nov 10 21:10:06 mail xrdp[19460]: (19460)(140578514478912)[DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
Nov 10 21:10:06 mail xrdp[19460]: (19460)(140578514478912)[DEBUG] TLSv1.1 enabled
Nov 10 21:10:06 mail xrdp[19460]: (19460)(140578514478912)[DEBUG] TLSv1 enabled
Nov 10 21:10:06 mail xrdp[19460]: (19460)(140578514478912)[DEBUG] Security layer: requested 3, selected 1
Nov 10 21:10:07 mail xrdp[19460]: (19460)(140578514478912)[DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.20.11.1port 3389)
Nov 10 21:10:13 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<demo@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=80.144.9.12, lip=10.20.11.1, mpid=19483, TLS, session=<VSxhXCPtgMJQkAkM>
Nov 10 21:10:15 mail dovecot: imap(demo@domain.com): Connection closed (FETCH finished 0.217 secs ago) in=195 out=942
```

Comment: **logs** - you want to check what dovecot has put into syslog/journal at the time it returned the error to the clients.

Comment: @anx thanks for your comment. I've edited the post with the logs from syslogs file.

Comment: That is not a lot of dovecot logging. Consider setting up [rawlog_dir](https://doc.dovecot.org/settings/core/#core_setting-rawlog_dir) to get transcripts of what your application is trying to do (don't forget to disable that later, it produces substantial log volume that is not automatically cleared).

Comment: Use `doveadm mailbox status -u user@domain mailbox` to verify that dovecot does see messages in the folder your are trying to fetch messages from. You will *always* get an error when trying to `FETCH` from an empty folder.